# Desktopless OS that can launch GUI programs

Tags: gui, operating-systems

I don't really know what this would be called so most likely this is a repost, but I can't find what it would be. My question is if there's a way to have an os that can launch programs with a GUI, but also don't have a desktop. Thanks

Comment: You could definitely *launch* programs that need a GUI without the desktop running - the program would just crash almost instantaneously. :) So the answer to your question is probably no.

Comment: you don't need a window manager ... if you are using Xserver then you can run your program without running a WM first ... you won't be able to move the program window and you won't be able to resize it, but it will definitely run ... unless it depends on the WM for support, of course

Comment: your question is not related to RPi .. it is a linux question ... https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-x-applications-without-a-desktop-or-a-wm

Comment: Oh alright, I considered it to be an RPi question because I was looking for an OS that would run on Raspberry Pi

Comment: What is the purpose of having no 'desktop'?  Are you trying to lock something down?  There may be other ways to achieve your goals.  If memory footprint is a concern, twm is an incredibly lightweight window manager (twm is Tabbed Window Manager).

Comment: Yes, i'm running on the original pi and wanted to save some memory as I mainly want to run one game (crossfire) and mainly use it as a server for my coding experiments without a window manager. I'm currently trying rpi server with xserver as jsotola suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be Raspberry Pi OS Lite. You can install GUI programs (such as SDL games) on it just fine: `apt` is smart enough to pull out dependencies for you.

If you want to run GUI programs which are designed to use the X server, there will obviously no way around installing it. This is the case for [crossfire](https://packages.debian.org/buster/crossfire-client). You rarely actually *need* a desktop per se to use such programs, but unless you have experience with X environment, you will be better served by the Pi OS with desktop.